# PyQt PySide6: End while-loop in worker-class (Thread QObject) by clicking a button on main GUI

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt, pyside6

I'm fairly new to GUI with Threads and Signals.
I read so many other questions and tutorials, but i can't figure it out.

Reason I do this: a Chatbot that is connected to IRC, fetches certain Info and processes it.
As a console-version this is all fine, but as a GUI I'm running into Problems.

This is my test setup just for testing to start/stop the thread:
[Example GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7O6o.png)

So the test is pretty simple:

**Start-Button** starts the Worker-Class (while loop appending the same 4 messages to the text-edit over and over until Stop-Button is clicked)

**Stop-Button** ends the loop -> disconnects IRC

Starting the Thread/Worker works, but on clicking the stop-Button I get the Error
***"AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'irc_connected'"***

I already tried so many setups of signals and slots that I'm confused more than in the beginning.

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Worker-Class:

```python
class Chat(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.irc_connected = True

    finished = Signal()
    update_text_edit = Signal(str)

    @Slot()
    def run_irc(self):
        while self.irc_connected:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.update_text_edit.emit("Message 1")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.update_text_edit.emit("Message 2")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.update_text_edit.emit("Message 3")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.update_text_edit.emit("Message 4")
        self.update_text_edit.emit("== END ==")
        self.finished.emit()

    def irc_disconnect(self):
        self.irc_connected = False

class Frm_main(QMainWindow, Ui_thread_test):
    button_signal = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # button
        self.bt_start.clicked.connect(self.update_text_edit)
        self.bt_stop.clicked.connect(Chat.irc_disconnect)

    def append_to_te(self, message: str):
        self.te_echo.append(message)

    def update_text_edit(self, message):
        # 2
        self.thread = QThread()
        # 3
        self.worker = Chat()
        # 4
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # 5
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run_irc)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.update_text_edit.connect(self.append_to_te)
        # 6
        self.thread.start()

        # result
        self.bt_start.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.bt_start.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.te_echo.append("== CHAT ENDED ==")
        )


app = QApplication()
frm_main = Frm_main()
frm_main.show()
app.exec()
```

UI:

```python
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy, QStatusBar, QTextEdit, QWidget)

class Ui_thread_test(object):
    def setupUi(self, thread_test):
        if not thread_test.objectName():
            thread_test.setObjectName(u"thread_test")
        thread_test.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(thread_test)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.bt_start = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bt_start.setObjectName(u"bt_start")
        self.bt_start.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 191, 71))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.bt_start.setFont(font)
        self.bt_stop = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bt_stop.setObjectName(u"bt_stop")
        self.bt_stop.setGeometry(QRect(210, 10, 191, 71))
        self.bt_stop.setFont(font)
        self.te_echo = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.te_echo.setObjectName(u"te_echo")
        self.te_echo.setGeometry(QRect(10, 170, 781, 371))
        thread_test.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(thread_test)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        thread_test.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(thread_test)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        thread_test.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(thread_test)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(thread_test)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, thread_test):
        thread_test.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("thread_test", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.bt_start.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("thread_test", u"Start", None))
        self.bt_stop.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("thread_test", u"Stopp", None))
```

Comment: `Chat` is a class. You need to connect the signal to the *instance method*: `self.bt_stop.clicked.connect(self.worker.irc_disconnect)`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I understand the approach, but when I connect the `self.worker.irc_disconnect` in the __init__ of Frm_main it doesn't work, beacause worker isnt created till then. When I initiate `self.thread = QThread(()` and `self.worker = Chat()` in the __init__ I don't get the Error, but clicking the button just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Obviously, you should connect it when you create the thread, and since you're going to do it in `update_text_edit`, you should connect it from there.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work either. The button has no function when I connect it in `update_text_edit`. But the Errror is gone.

Comment: Change to `self.bt_stop.clicked.connect(self.worker.irc_disconnect, Qt.DirectConnection)`.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. I never read about this anywhere.